# Given a position vector for a particle, determine when the velocity vector and acceleration vector are perpendicular

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

**Problem**

Given the position vector of a particle measured in $t$ seconds

$$\vec r(t) = [4t+2, \ 2t-5t^2]$$

find out when the velocity vector and acceleration vector are perpendicular to each other.

**My thoughts**

Velocity vector: $\vec v(t) = [4, \ 2-10t]$

Acceleration vector: $\vec a(t) = [0, \ -10]$

We know that the dot product needs to be 0 at this point. Thus we solve

$$4\cdot 0 + (2-10t)(-10) = 0 \ \Rightarrow \ \boxed{t = 5 \text{ seconds}}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: You are right sorry for that @cosmo5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all correct except for

$$ t = \dfrac{1}{5} s $$